# How to get the factorial value of each number in an array?

Tags: php, function, lambda, functional-programming

I am trying to get an factorial value of each item in array by using this method but this outputs only one value 
can any body help me finding where i am doing wrong?

```
   function mathh($arr, $fn){


            for($i = 1; $i < sizeof($arr); $i++){
            $arr2 = [];
          $arr2[$i] = $fn($arr[$i]);

        }
        return $arr2;
    }

    $userDefined = function($value){
       $x = 1;
         return $x = $value * $x;


    };

        $arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
        $newArray = mathh($arr, $userDefined);

        print_r($newArray);
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-fact.php

Comment: Hey Jay, I am actually trying to learn lambda functions, i know this can be done only using single function but i want to know is this possible as i am doing? if yes then need answer for that so that i can learn more functional programming

Comment: First of all, when I try to run your code $x is undefined.

Comment: I think initializing `$arr2` inside the for loop is going to be a problem.

Comment: sorry i skipped $x = 1; from the code

Comment: You're overwriting `$arr2 = []` each loop iteration.

Comment: It looks like `mathh` may be trying to reimplement `array_map`. Do you know about `array_map`?

Comment: jay how it is overwriting? i am giving it $i variable which get increment after each loop

Comment: Yes i know about Array_map but didn't used it much because i am very new to php just doing things in this way so that i can force my mind to come up with new answers,

Comment: Each time you run the for loop `$arr2` is reset before you give it `$i`

Comment: Ammmm yes this is because $arr2 is declared with in loop

Comment: If you put `$arr2 = [];` before the for loop you will get 4 results, not one.

Comment: what you think? what should i do now for this to work fine?

Comment: ok let me try that

Comment: The results are sill not factorials however.

Comment: yes that is what i was going to mention...

Comment: do i need to add loop in userdefined function too?

Comment: but what will be the logic in userdefined function for loop  (+_+)

Comment: See the logic in my answer

Comment: thank you so much Jay Blanchard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to need a little recursion so in order to do that you need to pass the lambda function into itself by reference:

```
function mathh($arr, $fn){
    $arr2 = []; // moved the array formation out of the for loop so it doesn't get overwritten
    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($arr); $i++){ // starting $i at 0
        $arr2[$i] = $fn($arr[$i]);
    }
    return $arr2;
}

$userDefined = function($value) use (&$userDefined){ // note the reference to the lambda function $userDefined
   if(1 == $value) {
       return 1;
   } else {
       return $value * $userDefined($value - 1); // here is the recursion which performs the factorial math
   }
};

$arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
$newArray = mathh($arr, $userDefined);
print_r($newArray);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 6
    [3] => 24
    [4] => 120
)
```

I wanted to expand on this some since you're essentially (in this case) creating an array map. This *could* be handy if you're doing additional calculations in your function `mathh()` but if all you want to do is use the lambda function to create a new array with a range you could do this (utilizing the same lambda we've already created):

```
$mapped_to_lambda = array_map($userDefined, range(1, 5));
print_r($mapped_to_lambda);
```

You will get the same output, because the range (1,5) of the mapped array is the same as your original array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 6
    [3] => 24
    [4] => 120
)
```

Comment: Wow. Passing the lambda to itself in the reference is a nice trick!

Comment: Wow Jay You are Awesome thank you so much this is what i was trying to do <3 May Allah Bless you brother :)